# Any supported AGP 8x cards on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, ati, graphics

I've aquired an old desktop (Acer Aspire T135) which currently has an Nvidia Geforce FX 5500 graphics card.

I've discovered that this card is unsupported by Nvidia on any version of Ubuntu after 12.04 so I'm looking at alternatives. One that came up is the Radeon 4670 but again this is unsupported by ATi past 12.04

Are there any 8x AGP graphics cards that will work to their full abilities (using either open-source or proprietary drivers) in 14.04 or am I looking at getting a new(er) PC?

If there are still some available - any suggestions on the best one?

Comment: With a 10 year old computer, your best bet is to drop the thing off at a recycling center and get a new(er) one.  A lot of companies get rid of 3 year old computers and are happy to get just a few bucks for them instead of throwing them in the trash.

Answer (score 1):

Your GPU is still has some support (in Ubuntu 12.04 and newer) from Nvidia as part of their legacy driver set.

The Nvidia driver version 173 are packaged for Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 - http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nvidia-173 which supports your GPU - http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/71303/en-us

Though they are legacy drivers they will receive occasional updates for compatibility and bug fixes - http://www.nvidia.com/object/IO_32667.html.

If you want full support you will need an 8 series or newer, which I don't think any were ever made with AGP (unless some special OEM versions).

Hopefully someone can provide details about ATi GFX cards (which I have only limited experience of in Linux).