# Graphics hardware warning when updating to 14.04

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 14.04

As I use Ubuntu at work I just update only LTS versions but now I'm not sure if I can/should. As my computer is now ten years old I would change if was mine but as it is owned by my employer I have to work with it. It's not a bad one, it runs fine (this was not true when still had Windows on it ;-).

When updating to 14.04, it warns about possible bad/slow performance with Unity 3D so I stop updating as I am at work, not my own computer.

As I understand from https://askubuntu.com/a/438958/25305 Nvidia Geforce FX 5500 graphics card is still supported in 14.04. Now, in 12.04, I have driver version 173 and unity 2d runs fine for me.

output of /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

```
OpenGL vendor string:   NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce FX 5500/AGP/SSE2
OpenGL version string:  2.1.2 NVIDIA 173.14.39

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          no
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

Should I update? Is it better to stay with 12.04?

Thanks

Comment: you can backup your system  and try to install 14.04 if worked ok then it's ok , if not restore your backup

however i tried the Nvidia on many versions and the best of them was the 14.04

Comment: Well, that's an option. But I prefer not to backup-try-restore as it is a time consuming option at work. At home I would surely try but not at work. Thanks.

Comment: This seems like it might be just an opinion, but anyway you say that Ubuntu 12.04 is working fine and Ubuntu 12.04 still has support until April, 2017, so what's the point of upgrading it?

Comment: Hi @karel you are right, there's no logical reason to always be updated. It is just the impulse to always install the latest distro and explore. With the question I also look for reasons to not upgrading, specially if there is any risk.

Comment: I've encountered various performance problems with Nvidia GeForce 7050, Nvidia GeForce 7025 and Nvidia GeForce FX 5200 under Ubuntu 14.04 (with or without proprietary drivers, depending on the GPU) with Unity. However, using another UI like Gnome Fallback (with Metacity, otherwise you may also have performance issues), lxde or xfce, it should run really fine. lxde is really interesting with very old GPU which do not support support OpenGL 1.4+, because llvmpipe (which may be really slow on old hardware) is not used as it is with higher-end UIs like Unity and Gnome 3. No Unity 2D in 14.04.